# Given a large set of integers find best match for the given input subset of integers

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization

I have a small set of integers S and a large set of integers L. I want to find a subset of L having best similarity or having the closest match to S. The two subsets are considered similar if the exact or scaled form of numbers match with each other.
e.g. subset {1, 3, 5} match with subset {7, 9, 11} because numbers grow in +2 order in each one of the subsets.

For example:

S = {1, 4, 6, 5}

L = {3, 400, 7, 3, 12, 18, 14, 500, 17}

answer = {3, 12, 18, 14}

Any solution algorithm? (preferably implementable in C# and I am also looking for algorithms that find a subset with a length not being equal to the input query subset).

Comment: This is way too informal. First you are talking about scaling (=multiplication-based), but show some additive solution. Your example somehow is a scaled one. It seems order matters but it's not formalized. The loss is also not defined (sum, sum of squares). This is way too broad!

Comment: @sascha, Tx.  Yes, I was described it in a hurry. After all it can be seen as this. If we see the subset of integers as a waveform, I want to find best match for a small waveform location in a very large waveform. The distance could be Euclidean distance. The scaled and time warped form of the input query has to be considered in the search.